# matching and splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, split

I have  a file1 with contents:

```
abc_1 (qst_0) bndk
cgn32 (mn_r_1) mncp
 dmj_2 (yst) pr1f
```

I want to match and split the file line by line. for which I use the following code:

```
path = sys.argv[1]
 with open(path) as f:
  data = f.read()
 unit = re.split(r"(.+\(.*\).+)", data)
 print(*unit)
```

It is able to split the first 2 lines, but in the 3rd line it gives an error saying
IndentationError: Unexpected Indent at line 3 of file1. Could you someone help me out?

Comment: What type of file is this? A text file you're loading with e.g. `with open(...)` ?

Comment: yes its  a text file

Comment: I cant make changes to the file

Comment: how can I change my regex so that it matches both patterns

Comment: @abcd, how are you loading text file in python? can you include that

Comment: yes edited the code

Comment: @abcd What is your desired output?

Comment: just to print all these using `print(*unit)`

Comment: I just want to store them to `unit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
unit = [line.strip().split(" ") for line in data.split("\n")]
print(unit)
```

output:

```
[['abc_1', '(qst_0)', 'bndk'],
 ['cgn32', '(mn_r_1)', 'mncp'],
 ['dmj_2', '(yst)', 'pr1f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is an indentation error?

- Indentation error in python refers to the wrong syntax with respect to the spaces.

Here in line 3 `data=f.read()` you haven't followed the syntax properly. So in this case your code hasn't even executed a single line from your input file.

Make sure that you've 4 spaces inside a block, while using python. The following should work.

```
import re
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]

with open(path) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print (re.split(r"(.+\(.*\).+)", line))
```

(or)

```
import re
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]

with open(path) as fp:
    split_lines = [re.split(r"(.+\(.*\).+)", line) for line in fp]

print(split_lines)
```

NOTE:

- You haven't mentioned on what basis you want to split the lines. Is it by spaces, "_" or ")"?
- Your current regex doesn't do it.

Comment: the indentation error is said to be at the file not the code